# How can I access an SSL client certificate from IIS using **PHP**?

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, client, certificate

I'm looking for the **IIS** equivalent of `$_SERVER ['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']` or the **PHP** equivalent of **.NET**'s `Context.Request.ClientCertificate`.

Or at the very least, I need to retrieve the common name (CN) and public key.

How do I access the client's SSL certificate?

## ***Update***

---

This question has NOT been answered.  I did not ask how to use **.NET** to access the certificate, I asked how to use **PHP**.  Please remove the duplicate answer and reopen.